ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setOnModelChange') at NgxCurrencyDirective.registerOnChange
Expectation is on click of browser back it should navigate to websites homepage but instead screen got stuck and in console below error is printed.
ERROR
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setOnModelChange')
 at NgxCurrencyDirective.registerOnChange (main.js:179085:24)
 at cleanUpControl (main.js:117684:23)
 at FormGroupDirective.removeControl (main.js:119752:5)
 at FormControlName.ngOnDestroy (main.js:120367:26)
 at executeOnDestroys (main.js:87499:20)
 at cleanUpView (main.js:87411:5)
 at destroyViewTree (main.js:87252:9)
 at destroyLView (main.js:87388:5)
 at ViewRef$1.destroy (main.js:92638:5)
 at ComponentRef.destroy (main.js:94492:19)


When the back button is pressed force a refresh on the screen, this will solve your issue.
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
onBackButtonClick(event) {
  location.reload();
}

You can also try the suggestion from Akk3d1s which might work. Here when the same route is navigated, we can trigger the component to reload by using onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
Reference Answer
